Determination of intra-run and inter-run repeatability
This question has also been asked on Biostars
Note that this question is specifically in relation to clinical validation and verification activities.
The field lacks established published standards, apart from CLSI documents that are not open-source and cost a non-insignificant sum. However, the technical reproducibility of Illumina sequencing has been well-documented in the literature for over a decade. This consistency is robust enough that this type of analysis primarily measures external factors such as technician differences or day-of-the-week effects. For non-noisy regions, the germline variant-calling congruence is expected to be 100% unless there are significant issues. While this is well-understood, the challenge lies in determining the sufficient level of statistical "modeling" required to demonstrate this rigorously (i.e. statistically sound manner).
Let’s say I have VCF files with germline variants from samples A and B.
Run1: A_rep1, A_rep2, A_rep3, B_rep1, B_rep2, B_rep3,
Run2: A_rep4, A_rep5, A_rep6, B_rep4, B_rep5, B_rep6
I don’t have any “truth” set let us just assume these are random whole-genome patient non-diseased samples.
For analytical performance I want to determine the variability within the run and between the runs per sample.
Does it make sense for me to compare the full pairwise-matrix table and then average it out for precision/recall etc...
Inter-run example (Run1):
Comparisons
A_rep1 > A_rep2
A_rep1 > A_rep3
A_rep2 > A_rep3
But also, I complete the table
A_rep2 > A_rep1
A_rep3 > A_rep1
A_rep3 > A_rep2
Essentially, since we don’t know which false positives (FP) are real, we need to treat them all equally. Ultimately, this will average out the signal, and then the average precision will equal the average recall.
But I don’t really know if this makes sense or how else to approach the problem given no ground truth.
Other alternatives:

Take all shared positives across all 3-samples as “the truth” and
then use that for each sample. But one bad sample will throw all the
rest off (but maybe that’s the point of the measurement). But maybe
this conservative approach is more appropriate?
Jaccard-index

Any thoughts/suggestions from people experienced in this would be greatly appreciated.
Is this the best I can do?
Many thanks

This question needs more clarity; it's hard to tell what you're asking. Please add additional context around what you're trying to do. In particular, make "this question" explicit.
